# How to parse an INNER JOIN in python

Tags: python, sqlite, parsing, flask

Let's say I have two tables : cakes and dudes.

A row of cakes in json looks like this :

```
{
    "id" : 0,
    "name" : "Carrot cake",
    "slices" : 8,
}
```

A row of dudes in json looks like this :

```
{
    "id" : 0,
    "name" : "Ahsoka"
}
```

I want to keep record of every person that ate a slice of cake.
For example, the json result would be :

```
{
    "id" : 0,
    "name" : "Carrot Cake",
    "slices" : 8,
    "eaten_by" : {
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "name" : "Ahsoka"
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "name" : "CT-7567 Rex"
        },
        {
            "id" : 9,
            "name" : "CC-2224 Cody"
        },
    }
}
```

To achieve this, I created a `cake_eaters` table. When someone eat a slice of cake, I add a record of it in this table.

Now, to get the result above, I make this call :

```
sql_get_cake_eaters = ''' SELECT * FROM cakes
    INNER JOIN cake_eaters ON cakes.id = cake_eaters.cake_id
    INNER JOIN dudes ON cake_eaters.dude_id = dudes.id '''
```

But, here is the result I get :

```
{
    "id" : 0,
    "name" : "Carrot cake",
    "slices" : 8,
    "dude_id" : 0,
    "name" : "Ahsoka"
},
{
    "id" : 0,
    "name" : "Carrot cake",
    "slices" : 8,
    "dude_id" : 3,
    "name" : "CT-7567 Rex"
}
```

Here is how I parse it :

```
query = db_connect.execute(sql_get_cake_eaters)
result =     {
                 'tasks': [
                     dict(zip(tuple(query.keys()), i))
                     for i in query.cursor
                 ]
             }
return (jsonify(result))
```

How can I parse the return to get the result parsed as in my example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you can have dicts with 2 identical keys. Cake name and dude name are under one key named "name" in your result. That needs fixing. Changing query key for dude name can be done by changing your SQL query to `SELECT *, dudes.name AS dude_name FROM ...` Anyways, once your query result is in a form like this:

```
result = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Carrot cake",
        "slices": 8,
        "dude_id": 0,
        "dude_name": "Ahsoka"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Carrot cake",
        "slices": 8,
        "dude_id": 3,
        "dude_name": "CT-7567 Rex"
    }
]
```

You can simply do:

```
cakes = {}
for row in result:
    cake = cakes.get(row["id"])
    if cake is None:
        cake = cakes[row["id"]] = {"id": row["id"], "name": row["name"], "slices": row["slices"], "eaten_by": []}
    cake["eaten_by"].append({"id": row["dude_id"], "name": row["dude_name"]})
jsonify(tuple(cakes.values()))
```

The result looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Carrot cake",
    "slices": 8,
    "eaten_by":
        [{"id": 0, "name": "Ahsoka"},
       {"id": 3, "name": "CT-7567 Rex"}]
  }]
```

Comment: `SELECT cakes.id, cakes.name, cakes.slices, dudes.id as dude_id, dudes.name as dude_name FROM cakes
    INNER JOIN cake_eaters ON cakes.id = cake_eaters.cake_id
    INNER JOIN dudes ON cake_eaters.dude_id = dudes.id`

Comment: Thanks a lot !  
What if I want to keep a record of the date when the dude ate that slice ? In the case of there is a variable inside the `cake_eaters` table, `date` for example, and this variable is not in `cakes` or in `dudes`. Where should I put it in the initial SQL call ?

Comment: `SELECT cakes.id, cakes.name, cakes.slices, dudes.id as dude_id, dudes.name as dude_name, cake_eaters.date  FROM cakes INNER JOIN cake_eaters ON cakes.id = cake_eaters.cake_id INNER JOIN dudes ON cake_eaters.dude_id = dudes.id` and `cake["eaten_by"].append({"id": row["dude_id"], "name": row["dude_name"]})` will have to become `cake["eaten_by"].append({"id": row["dude_id"], "name": row["dude_name"], "date": row["date"]})`

Comment: Thanks !  
As I wanted to also get cakes that have not been eaten yet, I changed the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  
My call now look like this : `SELECT cakes.id, cakes.name, cakes.slices, dudes.id as dude_id, dudes.name as dude_name, cake_eaters.date as eat_date FROM cakes LEFT OUTER JOIN cake_eaters ON cakes.id = cake_eaters.cake_id LEFT OUTER JOIN dudes ON cake_eater.dude_id = dudes.id`